# What are the use cases of C++20 Concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I found about Concepts while reviewing C++20 features. I found that they add validation to templates arguments  but apart from that I don't understand what are the real world use cases of C++20 concepts.

C++ already has things like `std::is_integral` and they can perform validation very well.

I'm sure I am missing something about C++20 concepts and what it enables.

Comment: Concepts are syntactic sugar for SFINAE. They don't allow anything that was previously _impossible_, but they make the syntax for accomplishing SFINAE _much_ more palatable.

Comment: consider [named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req). In some sense concepts have been around since the beginning, but only now they became first class citizens

Comment: @PatrickRoberts They help avoiding SFINAE, but they aren't syntax sugar for it. `if constexpr` also helps with that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts they do allow things that were previously impossible like SFINAE on variadic templated constructors, enabling disabling non-templated methods  or concepts subsumation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SFINAE (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) & [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)) was an accidentally Turing complete sublanguage that executes at overload resolution and template specialization selection time.

Turns out it is used a lot in template code.

Concepts and requires clauses are an attempt to take that accidentally useful language feature and make it suck less.

The origin of concepts was going to have 3 pieces; (a) describing what is required for a given bit of template code in a clean way, (b) also provide a way to map other types to satisfy those requirements non-intrusively, and (c) check template code so that any type which satisfies the concept is guaranteed to compile

All attempts at (a) plus (c) sucked, usually taking forever to compile and/or restricting what you can check with (a). (b) was also dropped to ensure (a) was better; you can write such concept map machinery manually in many cases, but C++ doesn't provide it for you.

So, now what is it good for?

```
auto sum( Addable auto... values )
```

that uses the concept of `Addable` to concisely express an interface of a template. Error messages you get when passing a non-addable highlight it isn't `Addable`, and the expression that doesn't work.

```
template<class T, class A>
struct vector{
  bool operator==(vector<t,A>const& o)requires EquallyComparible<T>;
};
```

here, we state this vector has a `==` if and only if the `T` does. Doing this before concepts is an annoying undertaking, and even adding the specs to the standard is.

This is the turing tar pit; everyting is equivalent, but nothing is easy. All programs can be written with I/O plus a `(a=(a-b);(a<0)?goto c:next` 3 argument instruction; but a richer language makes programs suck less. Concepts takes an esoteric branch of C++, SFINAE, and makes it clean and simpler (so more people can leverage it), and improves error messages.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the cleaner error messages. This was the major reason Stroustrup (and co-workers) put much effort into introducing concepts into the standard, it's not just "mere" syntactic sugar around SFINAE.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818  I think he was fast. See prior edits. Probably, a race condition ;)

Comment: @jeffbRTC usually no comments needed for such simple typos. I just wasnt sure if I understand what is written at first

Comment: @largest I often write these on a phone with disabled autocorrect (because autocorrect and code sucks) and a stupid tiny keyboard so I have access to ctrl/alt/arrow keys/etc.  Typopalooza.  Then I reread and fix typos.  In this case, I also submitted early before first reread, heck before I was done writing, so lots of junk got through.