# What problem do C++20 concepts really solve?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to understand what problems C++20 concepts are solving and how exactly they are helpful to the end user. I understand that it helps the compiler in resolving function calls, but from my cursory reading of it, from an end user standpoint, it doesn't seem to add much.

Consider this code:

```
void addToCollection(auto& collection, const auto& val) {
    collection.push_back(val);
}

int main() {
    vector<int> fooVec;
    addToCollection(fooVec, 15);
    
    unordered_set<int> fooSet;
    addToCollection(fooSet, 15);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler issues a very obvious message telling us the function `addToCollection` is not compatible with `unordered_set`.

```
error: no member named 'push_back' in 'std::unordered_set<int>'
    collection.push_back(val);
    ~~~~~~~~~~ ^
concept.cpp:34:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'addToCollection<std::unordered_set<int>, int>'
      requested here
    addToCollection(fooSet, 15);
```

Prior to concepts, you'd resolve a failure like this by providing an explicit template specialization.

```
template<>
void addToCollection(unordered_set<int>& collection, const auto& val) {
    collection.insert(val);
}
```

With concepts, it appears that the correct way to fix this is by placing a constraint on the function parameter type.

```
template<typename CollectionType>
concept HasPushBack = requires(CollectionType collection, typename CollectionType::value_type val) {
    collection.push_back(val);
};


void addToCollection(HasPushBack auto& collection, const auto& val) {
    collection.push_back(val);
}

void addToCollection(auto& collection, const auto& val) {
    collection.insert(val);
}
```

As an end user I don't see what advantages I get from concepts in this example—why should I go through the exercise of defining a type constraint when in fact, I could provide an explicit template specialization and be done?

Comment: "*As an end-user I don't see what advantages I get from concepts in this example*" OK... why do you think that *this* is what concepts is about? I mean yes, this is a thing you could use concepts for, but that doesn't mean that this specific problem is what concepts was engineered to solve.

Comment: Good error messages.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980/deciphering-c-template-error-messages , https://www.cppstories.com/2021/concepts-intro/#one-advantage-better-compiler-errors

Comment: I want to know what a concept is and what problems it solves too. I'm hoping someone will step up and write a great answer to make this a serious, canonical Q&A, unless of course that already exists somewhere and this would be a duplicate.

Comment: If you want to understand the justification for someone else's design decision, it is best to ask the people responsible - failing that, some existing documentation. Stack Overflow doesn't deal in subjective questions or rants. Not every tool will be useful in every circumstance or for every problem; instead of trying to figure out what benefit you get *in your example*, you should actively look for existing examples by others. So [please start with research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), [for example](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B20+why+use+concepts).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452122/what-are-the-use-cases-of-c20-concepts answer the question? I found it with the above search, and it also sounds to me like a much better phrasing of the underlying question.

Comment: With concepts, you only need *one* function.  https://godbolt.org/z/dnEnG53nd

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I had a very nice answer tailored to OP's example, which, I believe, is more factual than an opinion, and would really appreciate a reopen.

Comment: @康桓瑋: I think you can achieve the same with type traits rather than concepts.

Comment: @康桓瑋: That's super helpful to know. Thanks for furthering the discussion and facilitating learning. A refreshing change on SO!

Answer (score 2):

First, do not mistake a way that a tool can be used for "the purpose" of that tool. You *can* hammer a nail in with the butt-end of a screwdriver, but that isn't why we make screwdrivers.

Even so, the difference here is that your conceptualized version works on more types. Your specialized version only worked for `unordered_set` and *only* for `unordered_set<int>`. Any other type (`unordered_set<float>`, `set<int>`, etc) would fail. The conceptualized version works for any type with a `push_back` or `insert` (though I would also check for `insert`, so that you'd get a better error if the type doesn't have `insert`).

Second, this example doesn't really exercise concepts. Your code doesn't really define a "concept" here; it's just a test for a single, specific member function.

Concepts as a feature shine when you are building a series of significant requirements, with relationships between them. Iterators and ranges are the go to examples for their utility as a feature.

Before concepts, what can you say about this function declaration:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
auto &value(InputIterator it);
```

Well, from the text used, the parameter is expected to be an "InputIterator". But... what does that *mean*? "InputIterator" is just text; it doesn't mean anything by itself. You'd have to go to the documentation of the function to figure that out.

If you were using dynamic polymorphism with base classes, you could just go to the base class and see what the expected interface needs to be. The requirements of a derived class would be spelled out by the C++ code itself.

Concepts is a tool for doing that for compile-time static polymorphism. It is a way for spelling out the interface requirements of a template using actual C++ code, such that a user can have some idea of what they're expected to provide. It also ensures that the user actually provides that interface.

And it allows you to overload based on these interfaces. Not just function overloading, but class overloading. You can constrain class templates, and their member functions, on concepts.

You can easily make a class template that takes an iterator of any kind and generates an interface matching whatever kind of iterator is given to it. If the given iterator is only an `input_iterator`, then you can generate just the `input_iterator` functions. If it's a `random_access_iterator`, then you can generate those functions too. And while you could do that in pre-C++20 via SFINAE (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) & [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)) techniques, with concepts, this is about as trivial as it gets.

```
template<input_iterator It>
class mirror
{
public:
  iter_reference_t<It> operator*() const; //All input iterators can do this.
  mirror &operator++(); //All input iterators can do this.

  mirror operator+(std::iter_difference_t<It>n) requires random_access_iterator<It>; //Only random access iterators get this one.

  //etc.
};
```

Answer (score -3):

C++20 concepts primarily solve one problem: Error messages a human being can read.

They can make the code more readable too but that is more secondary.

Comment: Um, no. Making SFINAE-style requirements something a normal user can program is the main purpose behind the feature. Better error messages are good and an important part of the feature. But that is not "only one problem" that the feature solves.

Comment: Normal users don't program template libraries. They only use them. For users concepts are probably more work than benefit. Like in the given example. The plain template deduction works well enough without concepts.

Comment: "*Normal users don't program template libraries.*" That's tautological thinking. To the degree that is true, it is primarily because of the *lack* of features like concepts. With those features, the skill floor for writing such libraries drops and therefore they will be more able to write such things. The ideas behind templates and compile-time polymorphism aren't that complicated; it's the difficulty in expressing them in code that has been the primary impediment to their usage by normal users.

Comment: I use templates a lot, but simple user cases. Not highly complex cases you need to handle in template libraries like the STL. And the biggest problem with writing template code are those 100kB long error messages that are simply unreadable. Introduce concepts: Suddenly you get a nice 3 line error telling you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, if you show an example with and without concepts, to make your point, I'll upvote this. I just don't know enough to even write nor recognize an example of this yet.

Comment: Sadly, error messages from complex concepts (ranges and such) are as bad, if not worse, than from conventional SFINAE. ;_;

Comment: In my experience concepts fail earlier than SFINAE which produces less output. But experience may varry.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be entirely wrong. Even the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67452244/4561887) emphasizes the benefit of better error messages when it says: _"Concepts takes an esoteric branch of C++, SFINAE, and makes it clean and simpler (so more people can leverage it), **and improves error messages**"._

Comment: I'm upvoting this. [@jodocas also agrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452122/what-are-the-use-cases-of-c20-concepts/67452244#comment119223458_67452244): _"+1 For mentioning the cleaner error messages. This was the major reason Stroustrup (and co-workers) put much effort into introducing concepts into the standard, it's not just "mere" syntactic sugar around SFINAE."_

Comment: I'd still like to see an example though showing 1) SFINAE withOUT concepts, and a usage which results in a cryptic error message, 2) the same SFINAE done WITH concepts, and a usage which results in a clean and easy-to-understand error message.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: "*This answer doesn't seem to be entirely wrong.*" No, this answer claims that the feature "really **only** solve one problem". This over-emphasis on error messages to the exclusion of all else is what makes it wrong. Saying that it makes error messages (theoretically) better is fine. Saying that this is the "only" problem being solved is wrong.

Comment: Goswin, I recommend that you change the phrase "concepts _really only_ solve one problem" to "concepts _primarily_ solve one problem". Then, I think you'd possibly lose some downvotes and probably get more upvotes, and you'd have a more-correct answer. cc: @NicolBolas

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "concepts fail earlier than SFINAE" makes no sense as a claim. Failing to satisfy a concept is still causing a substitution failure. Concepts are simply a better way to achieve SFINAE than `enable_if`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Thanks, that sounds much better indeed.